# How to write polyfill of angular 1 dependency injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I need the code of angular dependency code in native javascript .
I mean as like in Angular 1 dependency injection says "you can't use my service until you will not inject into controller". So my Question is How can I write a function in core javascript by which I can't use any object functionality until I will not pass in as argument?

Comment: did you try anything..?

Comment: To me your question is vague. Are you just looking to be able to import code from other modules? If so there are many options out there, take a look at http://requirejs.org/ that might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Edison , I tried to do in javascript . but I am fail for this . can u please provide me a link or code which explain DI in javascript.

Comment: Hi bm_i . I am not looking to able to import the code . I know the concept of require JS but I am looking the functionality of DI in core JS.